# ClassCastException to disconnect HttpURLConnection casted from URLConnection with PowerMockito

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, classcastexception, powermockito, urlconnection

My connection works fine with:

```
URLConnectionFactory hadoopConnectionFactory = URLConnectionFactory.newDefaultURLConnectionFactory(cfg);
String url = "...";
URLConnection urc = hadoopConnectionFactory.openConnection(new URL(url));
urc.connect();
// Do something with urc.getInputStream()
```

And I've a test with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest({URLConnectionFactory.class})`:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(URLConnectionFactory.class);
URLConnectionFactory hadoopConnectionFactory = PowerMockito.mock(URLConnectionFactory.class);
PowerMockito.when(URLConnectionFactory.newDefaultURLConnectionFactory(anyObject())).thenReturn(hadoopConnectionFactory);
URLConnection urc = PowerMockito.mock(URLConnection.class);
PowerMockito.when(hadoopConnectionFactory.openConnection(anyObject())).thenReturn(urc);
PowerMockito.when(urc.getInputStream()).thenReturn(...);
```

With OK.

Now, I want to close connection with [HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272947) and disconnect() method. This works fine in code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urc;
conn.disconnect();
```

But in test can't be casted:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $java.net.URLConnection$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6fcf4cc9 cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

How can I support cast in test to disconnect this conection with PowerMockito?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but instead of:

```
URLConnection urc = PowerMockito.mock(URLConnection.class);
```

use:

```
URLConnection urc = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
```

Otherwise your mocked class is of the wrong type.

Comment: Oh yes! It's that simple like this. Thanks ewrammer for the solution.